# Program to convert videos by interpolating 30fps video to 60 fps similar to Splash Pro video player

Tags: editing

If you have tried Splash Pro video player, you will see that it will play 30fps videos in 60 fps by using some kind of motion interpolation technology.

I want to somehow use that technology to process my 30fps videos to 60 or higher fps.

I tried Smooth Video Project(SVP) and I don't know what to do with it. It seems to only convert only Youtube videos.

How do I get this technology and apply it to my videos? Can I do it in Sony Vegas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the objective of trying to up the frame rate?  All it really gains you is interpolation artifacts that will reduce the overall quality of your video.  It may help the smoothness a little on high frame rate LCD screens that don't have their own interpolation, but it will come at the cost of artifacts on screens that aren't LCDs or that apply their own interpolation to a higher frame rate than 60fps.

Comment: I want to make a 60 fps video. I have some 60fps videos available but I also have older 30fps video where I can't reproduce in higher fps. I can accept some visual artifacts as long the whole video I'm planning to make is consistent with frame rate.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you may want to consider frame doubling.  It's kind of a toss up on how noticeable it will be vs the artifacts, but frame doubling wouldn't produce motion artifacts and would still allow for incorporation of 30fps footage in a 60fps sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're exporting your finished project to a 60 fps format, your editing or compressing software will generally do some sort of conversion for you. It's not usually necessary to conform all your clips before editing.

If you have different options for how to handle the conversion, using "Optical Flow" or "Motion Estimation" options will interpolate frames. Depending on how good the interpolation is and the nature of the footage, this may look perfectly acceptable or horrible. As mentioned, you can try frame blending, too.

If your software doesn't do the conform automatically, you could try 3rd party tools. I know many people who have had good success with [Twixtor](http://revisionfx.com/products/twixtor/) from RE:Vision Effects. But there are others you can try as well depending on which application you're using.

Answer (score 0):

usually there are two ways to convert videos from 30 fps to 60 fps. Firstly simply copy every frame to the missing frame, in this case, you can watch video with the same quality. Secondly, interpolate the missing frames using Sony Vegas or Splash Pro video player, which will playback video with poorer quality probably. Therefore, it is better to film videos at 60fps.

Still, I have tried to use some conversion tools to [convert video to 60 fps](http://www.videograbber.net/convert-video-60fps.html) and surprisingly found the video quality is good. Maybe you can find some alternatives like this for solving your problem.